# Can't collapse/fold ace editor widget using Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, cypress, ace-editor

This is my first post so i hope i do it right.

I'm using Cypress and writing integration tests, as part of that i need to try and click on an Ace editor widget in a react app, the widget is inside a span and has a class such as "ace_fold-widget **ace_start ace_open**", when clicked manually the class changes to "ace_fold-widget ace_start **ace_closed**"

I can't seem to make it react to commands no matter the manner i try to interact with the element.
And i can't seem to find the solution to this problem anywhere else online.

So i tried using:

```js
cy.get('Ace widget element').click() (tried with force option too)

 cy.get('Ace widget element').invoke('have.class', 'ace_fold-widget ace_start ace_closed').trigger('change')

 cy.get('Ace widget element').trigger('mousedown')

 cy.get('Ace widget element').trigger('click')

 cy.get('Ace widget element').trigger('changeFold') (found that changeFold is an event for it)
```

Tried with plain JS:

```
cy.get('Ace widget element').then(function($input) {
    $input[0].setAttribute('test', 'my new value')
  })
  .should('have.attr', 'test', 'my new value')
```

'Ace widget element' is just an example. I'm using the proper locator in that place.

What would happen is the element would display as folded by the arrow image and change the class but it wouldn't actually fold the rows. So i tried chaining a trigger to that as well but to no avail. After any step after the element changes back to as it was.

Interacting with the parent element does not make a change either,
Tried triggering its 'changeFold' event but nothing as well.

The DOM looks like this:

[image: The ace folding element]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is `cy.get('Ace widget element')` is your attempt to get the correct DOM element?

Comment: No i just used it as an example, i have the correct locator in that field - cy.get('.ace_open')

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use the class names to select different parts of the widget, for example this will click the top fold button.

The result is that the folded text is removed from the DOM, so initially assert one of the code lines is visible then assert it's missing after the click.

```js
// this is a line within the fold button that should disappear

cy.contains('.ace_line', 'for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {')
  .should('be.visible')                                            

// this is somewhat crude, but it follows the hierarchy of the gutter control
// so it should accurately get the first fold button 

cy.get('.ace_gutter')
  .find('.ace_layer.ace_gutter-layer.ace_folding-enabled')
  .find('.ace_gutter-cell')
  .find('.ace_fold-widget')
  .eq(0)
  .click()

// now verify the code line has gone

cy.contains('.ace_line', 'for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {')
  .should('not.exist')
```

---

#### Inner fold buttons

Clicking the inner fold (the one on line #2) is a little tricky, it seems that the `scrollBehavior` affects the way it works.

Note, I'm testing with gutter indexes visible.

```js
// turn off scrollBehavior to click the inner fold button
Cypress.config('scrollBehavior', false)

// check target line is visible
cy.contains('.ace_line', 'alert(items[i]').should('be.visible')

// click the 2nd fold button
cy.contains('.ace_gutter-cell', '2')           // this is the gutter index
  .find('.ace_fold-widget')
  .click()

// verify the target line has gone
cy.contains('.ace_line', 'alert(items[i]').should('not.exist')

// verify the for-loop line is still present and visible
cy.contains('.ace_line', 'for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {')
  .should('exist')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, i tried it but it did not help, both ways it goes through and clicks successfully but nothing happens. Its still not hidden, its really puzzling...

Comment: The code above is a test that works on the ace editor demo page - would need more information to suggest why you don't succeed, or you can can run it yourself and try to figure out the differences.